# Unknown icon on my notification bar

Tags: 4.1-jelly-bean, notifications, notification-icons

A notification has started appearing on my Huawei Ascend Y300 that I do not recognize. I searched on Google but couldn't find what it means. My device is running Android v4.1 (Jelly Bean).

Here's a few images of the icon. It's the one to the far left in the first picture.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot find any official documentation on this icon, but [various](http://www.fonearena.com/blog/67585/huawei-ascend-y300-review.html) [sources](http://www.reddit.com/r/AndroidQuestions/comments/164ttu/light_bulb_symbol/) [across](http://www.modaco.com/topic/355216-strange-icon/) the Internet suggest that it means you have "Power Saving" mode enabled on your device. It looks like this is specific to Huawei's devices, and can be disabled in your settings.